Error with PgBouncer on Heroku with Django and Docker
I'm currently running into database issues due to too many connections with my Django & Postgres app hosted on Heroku. Before upgrading my database plan, I wanted to try solving the issue with pgbouncer. According to this article by Heroku, the Procfile would need to be updated from something like web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi to web: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi after provisioning the pgbouncer buildpack.
The thing is, I don't use a Procfile but a heroku.yml. Currently, my yml file has this:
run:
  web:
    command:
      - gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 my_app.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker


I tried updating the web command to this: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 my_app.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker but that gives me this error: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel: not found
I tried this answer as well, but get an pgbouncer: unrecognized service error.
Any ideas on how to solve this?
